How can I non-parametrically generate new geometry with machine learning?
Say, I have a few .stl files and want to non-parametrically generate a new geometry that is "interpolated" between the datset. For that, I plan on using neural networks that follows the patterns recognized from the dataset similar to this approach: https://www.neuralconcept.com/heat-exchanger-design
For classical or normal Neural Networks I'm used to, a predefined input shape is used. But for CAD files, the number of nodes may differ greatly according to its shape.
I could pad the dataset to match their size, but I don't think it is a good idea.
How can I generate a new, interpolated geometry with Neural Networks?
Only other way I could think of is Graph Neural Networks with a fixed number of nodes spread out the geometry.

TensorFlow & PyTorch: These libraries provide the core tools to build and train GANs, VAEs, and other deep learning models for geometry generation.
Open3D: A library for working with 3D data, which can help with point clouds, meshes, and 3D visualizations.
PyTorch3D: A library specifically designed for deep learning-based 3D shape representation and manipulation.
DeepSDF: A model that uses neural networks to represent 3D shapes as signed distance fields.

Hi Samrath. This is not even close to an answer. On top of that, it looks like this answer was generated by an AI assistant, which is not allowed on Stack Overflow. It's probably best that you remove this "answer".
